# PostgreSQL PGCopyOutputStream dropped connection

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.0

I am facing an issue where my database connection seems to get dropped midway of a `COPY` command from jdbc (using `PGCopyOutputStream`). Any idea why this could be happening. I am writing into a table with two columns of integers. I am on `PostgreSQL 9.0.3`.

```
java.io.IOException: Write to copy failed.
at org.postgresql.copy.PGCopyOutputStream.write(PGCopyOutputStream.java:84) ~[postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.copy.PGCopyOutputStream.write(PGCopyOutputStream.java:76) ~[postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar:na]
at 
    ...
    ...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Database connection failed when writing to copy
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.writeToCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:856) ~[postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyInImpl.writeToCopy(CopyInImpl.java:53) ~[postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.copy.PGCopyOutputStream.writeToCopy(PGCopyOutputStream.java:125) ~[postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.copy.PGCopyOutputStream.write(PGCopyOutputStream.java:82) ~[postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar:na]
... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:95) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.SendChar(PGStream.java:174) ~[postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.writeToCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:850) ~[postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar:na]
... 13 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening due to an earlier primary key constraint violation, that threw an exception and left the connection unusable.

Comment: Can you please explain, how did you realize that this was happening due to an earlier primary key constraint violation by looking at the logs, Can you please elaborate your solution. Thanks